# How can I update my BIOS on my Intel NUC6i7KYK for proper internet connection?

Tags: wireless, internet, bios, intel-nuc

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on an Intel NUC6i7KYK ("Skull Canyon" model).

Recently the wireless internet connection (wifi) performance has been horrendous - very slow around 1mbps or less download speed when my laptop chromebook gets 12mbps or more. Have run speedtests on the laptop & smartphone to confirm its just my NUC that's problematic. Really stressful as I play Dota 2 online for both casual and research (university) reasons. Often my ping in game jumps to 350-700 and stays there for 10+ minutes, sometimes it will be around 40ms but spike sporadically up to 350+. Loading basic pages like Google can take 30 seconds or more but sometimes its instant.

After hours of googling it seems one likely cause is an out-of-date BIOS - most recent version from Intel is 48 but I have 46.

I just tried updating using an 8GB SD card with the latest bios on it following instructions from this site https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005532.html

However, I recieved the error message:
"*BIOS has detected unsuccessful post attempt(s).

Possible causes include recent changes to BIOS performance Options or a recent hardware change.

Press 'Y' to enter Setup or 'N' to cancel and attempt to boot with the previous settings.*"

I've also tried hitting F4 in the bios menu to do a BIOS Recovery, but when I check the version in terminal its still 46, AKA it hasn't updated.

So my questions are:

- (1) What can I do to successfully update my BIOS?
- (2) How likely is it that a BIOS update will restore proper internet connectivity to my Ubuntu NUC?
- (3) What software package(s) are available for Ubuntu 16.04 that might be able to automate this update process for me and make it easier?

Relevant notes:

- My wireless modem is the NetComm Wireless NF4V; I live in New Zealand and am using the ISP www.orcon.net.nz . They have no reported service issues currently
- I have not yet tried plugging into my router with ethernet but plan on doing it ASAP (don't have long enough cable!)
- The SD card I'm using to try update BIOS is not, as far as I can tell, a "bootable" drive (though I might be wrong!? I took it out of my digital camera since don't have any spare USB sticks lying around)
- Other threads I found while googling the issue suggest that Intel NUCs are intrinsically bad with internet, AKA the metal casing or the wifi chip or something else adversely affect their internet connectivity - so could this be an issue with me as well and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It is possible that a BIOS update could help, but I doubt it. network connectivity is determined by how well your drivers fit your card. yes, some wifi cards are notoriously bad, especially in laptops.  the manufacturer tweaks the card to get it in their machine, which requires a tweak to the driver, (ie you have to use their driver)

Comment: If Intel provides a process to update my bios of my nuc, and that process doesn't work, I doubt there is much we can do.

Comment: @ravery Thanks very much for the response and info. So, to confirm, you are suggesting the following points? (1) an update of my wireless internet-related drivers may help the issue and (2) since some wifi cards can be notoriously bad, testing an ethernet cable instead could be a potential fix as well

Comment: yes to both statements. unfortunately, many manufactures provide little support for linux, which leaves you hunting through solutions to find a tweak that works for you. searching with wifi card model can help provide fixes or newer drivers

Comment: @ravery Intel is not one of those: 5 methods and 4 of them are supported through Linux https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005636.html?eu-cookie-notice using a bootable usb and 3 using a none-bootable usb.

Comment: @Rinzwind @ravery thank you both for your help. Regarding wifi drivers, I have just run in terminal the following code `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` followed by `dmesg | grep iwl` which yielded messages including `Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2` and `loaded firmware version 21.302800.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.755937] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 8260, REV=0x208` . What do these outputs mean? Sorry, I'm new to Linux, learning as I go.

Comment: @ivan make it a new question ;) Oh and we have someone on AU that can be considered The Ultimate Master of Wifi problems (chili555) so make sure to tag it "wifi")

Comment: he means [wireless] since there's no [wifi] tag (afaik)

Answer (score 2):

> (1) What can I do to successfully update my BIOS?

Nowadays my bios allows updating from bios itself.

Did you see [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005636.html?eu-cookie-notice) on the Intel site on upgrading NUC? It shows 3 options for Linux with video's. Your link points to 1 of those options but the more easier method to me seems to be [Power Button Menu BIOS Update Instructions for Intel® NUC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000006030.html).

Pick the bootable USB version and not one through an SD card. Those through a bootable USB work a lot better since it is done through a normal USB boot.

> (2) How likely is it that a BIOS update will restore proper internet connectivity to my Ubuntu NUC?

Unlikely. Unless that system has a seriously flawed design where the wireless is messed with by the systems hardware (metal casing with a badly placed NIC is not unheard of).

> (3) What software package(s) are available for Ubuntu 16.04 that might be able to automate this update process for me and make it easier?

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIOSUpdate for specific methods per manufacturer. Option 5 (using freedos has always been my best working method) IF the normal Intel methods with a bootable usb fail. Always go for a method by the manufacturer instead of a method by the OS.

> Other threads I found while googling the issue suggest that Intel NUCs are intrinsically bad with internet, AKA the metal casing or the wifi chip or something else adversely affect their internet connectivity - so could this be an issue with me as well and what can I do to fix it?

Yes, that could be the issue and the most efficient method would be to get a WLAN dongle and stop using your internal wireless. The more expensive ones are 50 euro (roughly 80 NZD acc. to google ;) ). That is besides returning the machine and getting another one ;)

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply.  I had actually already tried the Power Button Menu method - sorry, didnt explain that clearly. I will give the BIOS update another go soon using a Bootable USB. Purchasing a WLAN dongle seems a potentially easy solution, thanks, I've just seen one for $27 NZD!

Comment: Yeah I said "more expensive" ones. Mind that the cheapest often work but are not the best. And make sure you get a Linux friendly one ;) But I am betting you went wrong using an SD and not a bootable USB. Good luck ! :)

Comment: an excellent reminder... appreciate that!